# Buttons in a table in a div need to stay on edge of screen when window is resized

Tags: html

I have an interface with a header graphic and beneath that I have a set of 5 buttons.  The three on the left are set fine, but the two on the right (back and next buttons) need to dynamically reposition themselves depending on the window being resized or maximized.  The buttons reside in a table that is in a div.

How can I make the two buttons on the right reposition themselves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just float the table the buttons are in to the right.

```
#tablename { 
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them permanently fixed to a certain position in the screen you can use `position: fixed` and then `top:[#px]` and `left:[#px]` to move them around. If you only want them to reposition on resize you'll need to use Javascript to catch the event and apply CSS.